# How to insert a javascript function inside a modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an URL input and a submit button on my web page. When I press Submit, I want a modal to be opened, in which I can see the title, favicon and the description of the saved website, then I want the url added to a database I created and to refresh my page. These are the 3 things I'd like my button to do.

So far I've managed to make the button open the modal and show the website's title etc., but if I refresh my page, insert another url, and press Submit, the modal will show the meta tags from the first website saved.

I don't know how to fix that.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for styling and I have inserted the php script inside my modal.

Here is my code:

```
<body>

    <!--h2><?php echo "Wellcome " .$email ?></h2-->
<form role="form" method="post"><!-- am scos url.php de aici-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <br></br>   
    <label for="url">URL</label>
    <input type="url" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="Enter URL">
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target = "#Submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="Submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby = "SubmitLabel" aria-hidden = "true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Saved URL</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

      <?php

      $myServer = "localhost";
      $myUser = "root";
      $myPass = "'********'";
      $myDB = "social_bookmarking";

      //connection to the database
      libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
      $connect = mysqli_connect($myServer,$myUser, $myPass)
      or die("Couldn't connect to SQLServer on $myServer");

      //select a database to work with
      $selected = mysqli_select_db($connect, $myDB)
      or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

        //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
      $adress = "INSERT INTO url (url ) VALUES ('$_POST[url]')";
      $table = "ALTER TABLE url ADD CONSTRAINT constraint1 UNIQUE(url)";//ca sa nu se poata salva doua linkuri exact la fel
        //extract title
        if ( $_POST["url"] ) {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            @$doc->loadHTML( file_get_contents( $_POST["url"] ) );
            $xpt = new DOMXPath( $doc );
            $output = $xpt->query("//title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        } else {
            $output = "URL not provided";
        }
        //echo "Title:";
        echo $output;
        //var_dump($output);

        //extract favicon
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
        $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
        $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
        $arr = $xml->xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
        echo "<br>";
        //echo "favicon:";
        if( $arr)
        {
          $src = $arr[0]['href'];  
          echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
        }        

        //extract description
        $tags = get_meta_tags($_POST['url']);
        if(isset($tags['description']))
        {
          $description = $tags['description'];
          //echo "description:";
          echo $description;
        }    
        else
        {
          echo "<br>";
        }      

      //echo "Next $url = $_POST  ";
      $url = $_POST['url'];
      if (!empty($_POST['url']))    
      {
            // Instructions if $_POST['value'] exist
        echo "<br>";
            echo "Your url is:\n " .$url; 
        }
        else
        {
          echo "URL error\n";
        }

      if (!mysqli_query($connect, $adress)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Your information was added to the database";  
      }
      /*
      echo "Titlul:    ";
      echo $output;*/
        ?>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
  </div>  
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I inserted the php script inside the modal body. What am I doing wrong and how can I refresh the page after I saved my link? 
Thank you all in advance and excuse my coding mistakes, I'm a beginner.